# How can I do 8 questions with switch&case option?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, case

i must ask 8 question in my android app (java, with Android Studio), so I thinked to use SWITCH/CASE metod..I think ti use a code like this one but but the error is "Break out switch or loop". How can I correct this error?
as example, the app go to question 1, yes or no button and wait for a pressed button (yes or no), when I press yes or no button, the app continue to second case (second question, etc etc)

```
for(int loop=1; loop<=8; loop++){

        switch(loop) {
            case 1:

                question.setText(s);

                yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do something;
                        break;

                    }
                });

                no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do something;
                        break;

                    }
                }

                );
           case 2:

                question.setText(t);

                yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do something;
                        break;

                    }
                });

                no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do something;
                        break;

                    }
                }

                );
             etc etc
```

Comment: I use android studio and java for my android app..

Comment: The thing is that the code you put in `onClick` will not run until you click the button. And by the time you will click the button there will be no loop.  Why are you setting `onClick` listeners here in the loop just set them individually maybe in `onCreate` method and in the loop just break after setting question text.

Comment: I put setOnClickListener in onCreate, but the question go to the number 8 (end of the loop) immediately.. i think the loop go to number 1 case, pause, attend the on click on button one or two, and then go to number 2 case...